# Test CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, spinner, loading

I'm using the `ModalProgressHud` to display a spinner while it's waiting for an answer from the server. I want to test that when the user taps the button, the `CircularProgressIndicator` is shown. My problem is that the `pumpAndSettle()` will timeout because of this `CircularProgressIndicator` that, I think, it's constantly rebuilding itself. Any suggestion on how to test the presence of a `CircularProgressIndicator`?
This is my test:

```
testWidgets(
      'Should show a CircularProgressIndicator while it tries to login', (WidgetTester tester) async {

    await (tester.pumpWidget(
             generateApp(LoginView())
          ));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.tap(find.byType(FlatButton));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

Answer (score 8):

Your thinking is correct - you cannot `pumpAndSettle` because CircularProgressIndicator animates indefinitely. You could try using `tester.pump()` with a timeout instead of `pumpAndSettle`.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for you in case you need to implement **Golden** tests in the future.

As [MichaelM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64435/michaelm) said you should use `tester.pump()` instead of `tester.pumpAndSettle()`. I don't want to repeat the same answer but to let you know that in case you want to test a progress indicator or other animated widgets while doing **Golden** tests, you should set `pump` as the pump type for the golden test because by default it is set to `pumpAndSettle` and the tests will fail.

```js
await screenMatchesGolden(
  tester,
  'loading_page',
  // The custom pump (tester.pump) only show a frame of
  // a never-ended animation like `CircularProgressIndicator`,
  // otherwise the default pump (tester.pumpAndSettle) waits
  // until the animation ends (infinite) and it timeouts.
  customPump: (tester) async => await tester.pump(
    // We need to provide a duration to make the fake timer
    // advance, otherwise it remains on the 0 time slot and
    // raises an exception.
    const Duration(milliseconds: 20),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a "loading" `bool` and use `setState((){})` before your login screen and another when you evaluate whether the login was successful or not.

I'm not exactly sure how to follow your code but maybe something like this...

```
bool loading = false;

testWidgets(
      'Should show a CircularProgressIndicator while it tries to login', (WidgetTester tester) async {

    loading == false ? setState((){
             loading = true;
             await (tester.pumpWidget(
             generateApp(LoginView())
          ));}
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.tap(find.byType(FlatButton));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

Comment: How can you use the setState here?

Comment: In my example above I used an if statement/ternary operator to determine the status of `loading` and then set the state to loading = true, present your CircularProgressIndicator, and present the Login Screen.  After a successful login set the state to loading = false, dismiss the ProgressIndicator, and navigate to the next screen.

Comment: `setState` in your example in undefined.

Comment: Its better to separate state and view by using the BLoC Pattern or similar designs. This will enable testing of widgets much more easily. [Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4074597-getting-started-with-the-bloc-pattern)